# Compiler gets warnings when using strptime function (C)

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, strptime

Typing `man strptime` it sais that this function needs to have declared _XOPEN_SOURCE and included time.h header. I did it. But, when I try to compile my code I get:

> ./check.c:56: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strptime’

Look at my code:

```
int lockExpired(const char *date, const char *format, time_t current) {
        struct tm *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct tm *));
        time_t lt;
        int et;

        strptime(date, format, tmp);
        lt = mktime(tmp);
        et = difftime(current, lt);

        if (et < 3600)
                return -et;

        return 1;
}
```

Also the function declaration is:

`char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, struct tm *tm);`

Can anyone tell me where my problem come from?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've found that I needed to define `__USE_XOPEN` and also `_GNU_SOURCE` to get it to be happy.

Comment: That was it, thanks! It is strange that `man strptime` is wrong on my Linux machine; it writes `_XOPEN_SOURCE` which does not work for me. That being said, I am not sure about `_GNU_SOURCE` though. `__USE_XOPEN` seems to work on its own for me.

Comment: make sure you use `#define __USE_XOPEN` before you use `#include <time.h>`

Answer (score 1):

The manual page provided by Debian says:

```c
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <time.h>
```

The comment shouldn’t be disregarded. Indeed, by running `man 7 feature_test_macros` you will learn that:

> In order to be effective, a feature test macro *must be defined before including any header files*.

So just move the `#define` line to the very top of your source file and it will work just fine.